# error when install shap in Jupitor Notebook

Tags: python, shap

I got this error when trying to install shap in Jupitor Notebook. Would any expert here help me to fix it?

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for shap
Failed to build shap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for shap which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ef816dd6ade6> in <module>
      1 # Install and then reconnect.
      2 get_ipython().system(' pip install shap')
----> 3 import shap

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shap'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the ***shap*** module to the Jupyter environment. Just run `!pip install shap` in a different cell.

Comment: I've add but still have this error

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your pip version is up-to-date by running:
!pip install --upgrade pip

If the issue persists, you might be facing system-specific problems. In that case, you can try installing SHAP using the following command that includes the --no-cache-dir option:

!pip install shap --no-cache-dir